Is there a way to block a word (or RegEx) from compiling in C#?
I keep all of my project's "secrets" (API keys, database details, etc) outside the application and programmatically access those - both in development and in production.  Is there a way, given a list of prohibited strings, I could set up Visual Studio to stop compiling if it sees one of them?
Just really trying not to commit them to the repo (...again).
I reviewed the options in the editorconfig, but that won't do the trick.

Only be using Preprocessor Directives : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

You can do this writing  code analyser... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Of course, if I'm John Junior Programmer, someone with no knowledge of your secrets, and I coincidentally use "s0m3b1gs3cr3t" as a string in my code, and I get an error message, then you have leaked your secret

A git hook would be a better choice if you are trying to prevent the commit itself. Maybe something like https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets ?

A compile-time exception might seem like a good idea at first, but then you should realize that if there's a compile-time exception, it must contain a message that will allow you to understand the problem and fix it - and as @Flydog57 wrote - the only way to do it is to expose the secret to the developer, something you probably should avoid.

A good secret is cryptographically random. There's no way to match on random other than putting the secret in as the thing you match for. That's a Catch-22.

1.You can use the  pre-build event to call a simple script to check for cs files
2.Custom Roslyn analyzer.
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression);
    }
    private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var literalExpression = (LiteralExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
        var literalValue = literalExpression.Token.ValueText;

        // Case insensitive check for "password" substring
        if (literalValue.IndexOf("password", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, literalExpression.GetLocation(), literalValue);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }

Unit Test:
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VerifyCS = Analyzer1.Test.CSharpCodeFixVerifier<
    Analyzer1.Analyzer1Analyzer,
    Analyzer1.Analyzer1CodeFixProvider>;

namespace Analyzer1.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Analyzer1UnitTest
    {
        //No diagnostics expected to show up
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            var test = @"
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class {|#0:TypeName|}
        {   
public string str=""123password123"";
        }
    }";

            await VerifyCS.VerifyAnalyzerAsync(test);
        }


As Jeremy  said, use git hook.

